# Plot two functions in one plot in rstudio

Tags: r, function, plot, parametric-equations

I have two functions

```
fun1 <- function(x) -(2 * (sin(x) * cos(x)))
fun2 <- function(x) 2 * (cos(x) * sin(x))
```

I want to plot them both in one diagram. I have the parametrization

> \gamma (x) =(-2*sin(x)*cos(x),2*cos(x)*sin(x))

And actually if it was possible I want ONE function (ex.fun3) where both is defined and then plot fun3 instead of defining one for each.
Can someone help me with both questions?

Regards,

s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check here
```

https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/ggplot2-stat-function

```
fun1 <- function(x) {-(2 * (sin(x) * cos(x)))}
    fun2 <- function(x) {(2 * cos(x) * sin(x))}
    ggplot(data=data.frame(0)) + stat_function(fun = fun1) + stat_function(fun = fun2)+xlim(-3,3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to define a function 
fun3=(fun1,fun2)

Comment: when trying to use above, it says error could not find function ggplot

Comment: ok you have to install and load ggplot2 library: install.packages("ggplot2");library(ggplot2) and then run the code